# Dictionary comprehension to avoid lines of code

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Hi want to understand how to make this code shorter using dictionary comprehension:

```
for e in list_of_tuples:
            tmp = mydict.copy()
            tmp[e[0]] = tmp[e[1]]
                if someFunction(tmp):
                    mydict = tmp
```

I would like to pass a dictionary comprehension to `someFunction` instead of relying on a temporary dictionary whose values are changed in the loop. Is it possible?

Comment: does this code works? can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: You are using `tmp` for **two** things: to pass to `someFunction` and to then bind `mydict` to it. What is the binding for?

Comment: Sorry, realized that I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I think I see what you want here; you want to build `mydict` from a dict comprehension, but only with keys that leave the *whole* dictionary in a consistent state. That's probably not going to work then, as `someFunction` wants to have access to the *partially* constructed dictionary, which is not available in a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer assumes that someFunction does not alter the dictionary**

The dictionary passed to `someFunction` is still going to be a basic copy of `mydict`, but this is the only way I can think of answering the question with comprehension.

```
for e in list_of_tuples:
    if someFunction({key: val if key != e[0] else mydict[e[1]] for key,val in mydict }):
        mydict[e[0]] = mydict[e[1]]
```

However the faster/ easier way would be to just make a temp variable for `mydict[e[0]]`, and change it back after if `someFunction` fails. Also having extra lines isn't always a bad thing. It can usually help readability, solving bugs and maintenance.. especially for newer programmers.

```
for e in list_of_tuples:
    temp = mydict[e[0]]
    mydict[e[0]] = mydict[e[1]]
    if not someFunction(mydict):
        mydict[e[0]] = temp
```

Comment: The dict comprehension is overkill here if `e[0]` is always a string; `dict(mydict, **{e[0]: e[1]})` would accomplish the same.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, I agree completely. But if we don't know the data type of the keys, how else could it be created as a one liner?

Comment: what is this ** syntax in this context?

Comment: @Jasper `**` is used to expand maps/dictionaries usually for keyword arguments..  `*` is used for lists. ie `*(a, b)` -> `a,b`, `**{'a':1,'b':2}` -> `a = 1, b = 2` Read up here for its use in `dict` https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict